# ANOVA for four groups where individuals appear in each group

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, repeated-measures

I would like to calculate an ANOVA between four groups. Each group has 82 elements, i.e. for each group I have a vector of size 82. The groups describe the average typing speed on the left side of the keyboard, right side of the keyboard, from left to right and from right to left. Each individual has one value for each group. For example,

```
group1 = [w1, w2, w3,..., wn]
group2 = [x1, x2, x3, ..., xn]
group3 = [y1, y2, y3, ..., yn]
group4 = [z1, z2, z3, ..., zn]
```

n is 82. w1, x1, y1 and z1 is the typing speed on the left, right, left to right and right to left for person 1. w2, x2, y2, z2 is the typing speed for person 2 etc.

Is it valid to use ANOVA here because a person appears in every group?

Comment: Are data normally distributed as required for ANOVA? Block design with 82 randomly chosen subjects as blocks. Main effect is type of typing speed.  If data not normal, then maybe nonparametric Friedman test to see if main effect is significant. // If ANOVA, then model: $Y_{ij} = \mu + \tau_i + S_j + e_{ij},$ where $i=1,2,3,4, j = 1,2,\dots 82.$ No interaction term. $S_j\; IID\; \mathrm{NORM}(0,\sigma_\tau), e_{ij}\; IID\; \mathrm{NORM}(0,\sigma_e).$// Some might call it a 'repeated measures' design, but that terminology has  been over-used to the point of being almost meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

You have repeated measures data, see posts under the tag [repeated-measures](/questions/tagged/repeated-measures). You can model this with a mixed model, with a random intercept for each individual. In R you could use something like

```r
library(lme4)
mod0 <- lmer(speed ~ group + (1 | individual), data=your_data_frame)
summary(mod0)
```

As pointed out in comments, there might be other alternatives, but I would guess that normal-theory models wold work well for typing speed.

Try a model and look at residuals.